# Regular Expressions in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I  am trying to write a regex to match a particular line and perform action on the line below it . Reading the file `a.txt`
The contents of `a.txt`

```
I am from Melbourne .

Aussie rocks   #The text can be anything below the first line
```

I am writing a regular expression to read the file `a.txt` and trying to replace the text below `line 1`.
Snippet :-

```
open($fh,"a.txt") or die "cannot open:$!\n";
while(<$fh>){
 if($_=~/^I am from\s+.*/){
   #I have to replace the line below it .
}
```

Can anyone please help me. I just have to `replace a line below the line that matches my regex with an empty line or anything` .
`$line =~ s/<Line below line1>//;` . How can I do that .?

Comment: Replace with what? Can you please add the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Replace it with anything . Preferably an empty line

Comment: I think `sed` could be quicker and simplier, for this jobs: `sed -e '/^I am from /{N;s/\n.*$/\nNothing or else../}' <a.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a *variety* of ways.

#### Read the next line in the loop:

```
while (<$fh>) {
  print;
  if (/^I am from/) {
    <$fh> // die "Expected line";  # discard next line
    print "Foo Blargh\n";          # output something else
  }
}
```

which is my preferred solution.

#### Use a flag:

```
my $replace = 0;
while (<$fh>) {
  if ($replace) {
    print "Foo Blargh\n";
    $replace = 0;
  }
  else {
    print;
    $replace = 1 if /^I am from/;
  }
}
```

#### Slurp the whole input:

```
my $contents = do { local $/; <$fh> };
$contents =~ s/^I am from.*\ņ\K.*/Foo Blargh/m;
print $contents;
```

That regex needs an explanation: `^` matches a line start under `/m`. `.*\n` matches the rest of the line. `\K` doesn't include the preceding pattern in the matched substring. The `.*` matches the next line, which is then replaced by `Foo Blargh`.

Answer (score 2):

```
open(my $fh, "<", "a.txt") or die $!;

my $replace;
while(<$fh>){
  $_ = "\n" if $replace;
  $replace = /^I am from.*/;
  print;
}
```

or by reading file at once,

```
open(my $fh, "<", "a.txt") or die $!;
my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };

$str =~ s/^I am from.*\n \K .*//xm;
print $str;
```

Comment: Nitpick: Your two solutions are not equivalent. #2 will skip empty lines after the initial line, whereas #1 does not. I.e. in #1, the `\s+.*` in the pattern is irrelevant.